# Can we have '+' operator inside printf()?

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf

```c
void main(){
    char str1[10] = "Hello", str2[10] = "World";
    printf(5 + "Good Morning\n");
}
```

The above code outputs:

> Morning

And I am not getting why.

Comment: What output are you expecting? What you've posted is valid code. (Though... "%s" is recommended.)

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: You really need to to learn some basic things about C, since it does no work at all how you seem to expect it to. And learning by trial and error is going to be extremely painful and very, very difficult. I suggest getting a good book.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens when I adding an int with a plus sign after the string within printf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707276/what-happens-when-i-adding-an-int-with-a-plus-sign-after-the-string-within-print)

Answer (score 8):

The array `"Good Morning\n"` (type `char[14]`), in the context of addition to an integer, gets converted to a pointer to its first element (the `'G'`).

That pointer is incremented by 5 and so points to the `'M'`.

```
G o o d _ M o r n i n g
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
```

The `printf()` receives the string `"Morning\n"` as the *format string*. As it has no `%`, it's ok and printed directly.